# What is the approximation for odd cycle transversal?

Tags: graphs, approximation, graph-traversal, bipartite-graph

What is the best approximation for odd cycle transversal?    (on general graphs) 
Sorry if this is easily found  everything I found about odd cycles is about paramaterized complexity and kernels

Comment: if you're looking for an approximation, what level of precision are you seeking?

Comment: I'm looking for an approximation algorithm for odd cycle transversal on general graphs

Comment: yes, but what does it mean to approximate odd-cycle traversal, and what level of approximation is sufficient?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I mean return an odd cycle transversal of cost at most a*OPT   where OPT is the smallest cost of a solution 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm#A_Posteriori_Guarantees
p.s. why does it not allow me to change the tag from approximation to approximation algorithm??    I want to change the tag as I realize it's the wrong tag